# Angular component syntax, callback function called with wrong context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an angular app using the [NG6-Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter) boilerplate.

Now, i've got one component with another component inside it, and i'm sending a callback function to the inner component via an attribute. This is how i'm initializing the inner component:

```
<div>
<location-form location='vm.location' submit-callback='vm.addLocation'>
</location-form>
</div>
```

The `addLocation` function on the parent controller gets called, but the problem is it's being called with `this` being the controller of the child component (location-form).

I tried using bind, but angular has issues with that.. 
Any ideas?

Component definition:

```
import template from './locationForm.html';
import controller from './locationForm.controller';
import './locationForm.styl';

let locationFormComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    location: '=',
    submitCallback: '=',
    parentController: '='
  },
  template,
  controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};

export default locationFormComponent;
```

Controller:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.submitCallback(vm.location)">
     ...
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: Can you post your directive code?

Comment: Added. Right now i'm solving it by passing the parent controller as a prop

Comment: if you want your directive to have the same parent controller/scope (vm) as it's parent, you can define `scope: false`

Comment: And controller code is?..

Comment: the controller isn't really relevant since the function being called is called from the view and it's the callback function

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. So far, the solution that worked for me was to pass the scope to the component / directive, and then use apply to make sure it calls the callback with the correct scope.